# Searching a field with first two characters in UPPER

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I am trying to query a sql server table which has value of ONeil. My goal is to add an apostrophe to the data that is queried. I know it would be easier to fix to problem from the source (in PHP) but have no access to those scripts

Table structure,

```
ID      First_Name     Last_Name
1       John           ONEil
2       Sam            OMally
3       Sarah          OConner
```

Comment: Make sure you don't convert ALL UPPER last names by mistake. For example SMITH.

Answer (score 0):

You can do string comparison of the first 2 characters to find out which records have last name beginning with 2 capital letters like so:

```
create table test (Last_Name varchar(50));
insert into test values ('ONEil'), ('OMally'), ('OConner'), ('Michaels');

select * from test where hex(left(Last_Name, 2)) = hex(upper(left(Last_Name,2)))

Result:
Last_Name
ONEil
OMally
OConner
```

To update those records, you could do:

```
update test
set Last_Name = concat(left(Last_Name, 1), '''', mid(Last_Name, 2, length(Last_Name)-2))
where hex(left(Last_Name, 2)) = hex(upper(left(Last_Name,2)))

select * from test;

Results:
Last_Name
O'NEi
O'Mall
O'Conne
Michaels
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8165e4/2

Comment: What about ALL UPPER like MICHAELS for example?

Comment: In the solution above, MICHAELS will become M'ICHAELS

Comment: From my understanding, that's what the OP wants. Your perspective may be different, and I respect that.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for string that first two character are uppercase:

<kbd>**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376312)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   ID         INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,First_Name VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,Last_Name  VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES (1,'John','ONEil');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES (2,'Sam','OMally');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES (3,'Sarah','OConner');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES (4,'Sarah','Smith');


SELECT 
  ID,
  First_Name,
  Last_Name = CONCAT(LEFT(Last_Name, 1), '''', RIGHT(Last_Name, LEN(Last_Name)-1))
FROM #mytable
WHERE Last_Name LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Output:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ First_Name ║ Last_Name ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ John       ║ O'NEil    ║
║  2 ║ Sam        ║ O'Mally   ║
║  3 ║ Sarah      ║ O'Conner  ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: This would convert SMITH to S'MITH if you had someone in all upper.

Comment: @MichaelY. Yes the title of question `Searching a field with first two characters in UPPER`.

Comment: Yes, I can see the title. If you read the body of the question, you'll see what the intent is.

Comment: @MichaelY. So how you will handle `SMiTH`. There is universal rule **Garbage In => Garbage Out**.

Comment: I do agree about GIGO :)

Answer (score 0):

Table

```
mysql> select * from names where LEFT(last_name, 2) = UPPER(LEFT(last_name, 2));
+-----------+
| last_name |
+-----------+
| Michael   |
| Blah      |
| ONeil     |
+-----------+
```

Update query

```
update names
set last_name = concat(left(last_name, 1), '\'', right(last_name, length(last_name)-1))
where binary left(last_name, 2) = upper(left(last_name, 2))
  and binary upper(left(last_name, 3)) <> left(last_name, 3);
```

Result

```
+-----------+
| last_name |
+-----------+
| Michael   |
| Blah      |
| O'Neil    |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the last_name field where the 1st 2 characters are uppercase to include an apostrophe, then I would issue an update query:

```
update tablename set last_name=left(last_name,1) + char(146) + substring(last_name,2)
where binary upper(left(last_name,2))=left(last_name,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a little more clarification, but I imagine you want to return `O'Neil` instead of `ONeil` when the first 2 characters are upper case but return `Oneal` if they aren't?

If so, here's an option using collate, case, upper, left and right...

```
select id, first_name, last_name,
  case when left(last_name,2) = upper(left(last_name,2)) 
                                    collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
       then left(last_name,1) + '''' + right(last_name, len(last_name) - 1) 
       else last_name
  end as new_last_name
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1afb8de/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two functions to do it.

The first one is SUBSTRING (cut first two letters)
And the second one is ASCII (the number in ASCII of uppercase start from 41 to 5A)
It can help you to find two first uppercase letters.

Read more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx